# FullText Search implementation on SQL server 2008 Problem

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have the following Stored procedure,

```
CREATE Procedure sp_SearchDB (
  @SearchWord nvarchar(200)
)

SET @SearchWord = '"*' + @SearchWord + '*"'

 Select * 
   from Table1
  Where Contains(Description, @SearchWord)
```

When I search "SQL Server", it returns me results with "SQL" or "Server", but it will not return data with "SQLServer"(if there is no white space), similarly if give searchword=SQLServer, it will not return "SQL Server"(with white space). How can I get both results "SQL Server" and "SQLServer"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the procedure as follows:

```
EXEC sp_SearchDB N'SQL SERVER'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I have tried that,but it does not work. It returns rows only with SQL or SERVER or [SQL SERVER] but it will not return SQLServer(with no white space).

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to execute your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, you can do it, but it will give you some false positives. Try:

```
EXEC sp_SearchDB N'SQL'
```

With you do care about false positives, them the answer is: there is no way of doing that. If you want both "SQL Server" and "SQLServer" you should do:

```
Select * from Table1 Where Contains(Description, '"SQL Server" OR "SQLServer"').
```

You can write a code that will always try do find for both words together and separated. If your customer searches for:

```
baby sitter
```

Your code will create this variations when it finds a white space:

```
'"baby sitter" or "babysitter"'
```

I hope you get it.